# How to replace a invalid method input with a verifying method?

Tags: java

How do I make my verifying method replace the initial invalid input of
 a method. Like changing an invalid negative number from the variable
 `'r'` to the new input of `"verify"`. Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Cylinder {
    private static final double PI = 3.1416;

    private double radius;
    private double height;

    public Cylinder() 
    {
        radius = 1.0;
        height = 1.0;
    }

    public Cylinder(double r, double h) {
        radius = h;
        height = r;
    }

    private double verifyData(double verify, String confirm) 
    {
        verify = radius;
        verify = height;

        while(verify <= 0) 
        { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input");
            confirm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new value");
            verify = Double.parseDouble(confirm);
        }
        return verify;          
    }

    public void setRadius(double r) {
        radius = r;
        verifyData(r, null);
    }

    public void setHeight(double h) {
        height = h;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return (PI * Math.pow(radius, 2) * height);
    }

    public double getSurfaceArea() {
        return ((2 * PI * radius * height) + (2 * PI * Math.pow(radius, 2)));
    }

    public static double convertInchesToFeet(double r) {
        return r / 12.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is wrong with what you are doing?

Comment: I cant figure out how to replace 'r' if i set it to a negative number with  a valid number with "verify"

Comment: `r = verifyData(r, null);`

Comment: aslo, why `verify = radius; verify = height;`  in `verifyData()` ? you are setting the height in the parameter your just received. Same with confirm, don't expect the `String confirm` to be a pointer to return the new value.

Comment: why do you have a confirm variable?